# Can foo.example.com set a cookie for bar.example.com?

Tags: cookies

I'm setting these cookies for a single sign on solution where I have one app running at foo.example.com and a different app running at bar.example.com.

I know that I can set a cookie from `foo.example.com` for `.example.com`.

If I had control over bar.example.com I'd just have it recognize a cookie from `.example.com`. But I have very little control of it.

For what it's worth, the app at foo.example.com is in python and the app at bar.example.com is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certianly try. However, browsers should not honor this behavior as it is a [`cross-site cooking attack`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_cooking).

Comment: I agree that it appears to be a cross-site cooking attack but because they are different sub-domains on the same domain it is kind of a gray area. However, thinking about sites that offer sub domains like weebly.com, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. SSO is done using protocols such as OAuth or SAML that imply sending signed messages between the endpoints and/or communication between them. There is no way to do this on the "client side".

Comment: I agree. I wish that bar.example.com had more of an api or configurable authentication. :(